# "Missing required module 'XYZ'" on Unit Tests when using Swift Package Manager

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm using Swift Package Manager on an iOS app on Xcode 11 following the instructions from https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/408/

Everything looks great, except Unit Tests won't work now.

[image: Navigator panel]
[image: Project setup]
[image: Error]

Comment: I had almost the exact same issue. It turned out to be due to a custom build configuration I had created. It started working again after I set the Test build configuration back to Debug in the scheme editor. Hope that helps.

Comment: @JeffreyFulton Can you explain why this is needed? I'm facing a similar issue with Firebase even though I don't use Firebase in any of the unit tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After researching a bit, I got this fixed by adding `-Xcc -fmodule-map-file=$(PROJECT_TEMP_ROOT)/GeneratedModuleMaps/macosx/<missing module name>.modulemap` to `OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS` in the test target.

Source:

- https://github.com/apple/swift-nio/issues/1128#issuecomment-527566361
- https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/2057#issuecomment-538371425
- https://github.com/swift-aws/aws-sdk-swift/issues/167#issuecomment-527650662

PS: Use `-Xcc -fmodule-map-file=$(PROJECT_TEMP_ROOT)/GeneratedModuleMaps/iphonesimulator/<module name>.modulemap` if your platform is iOS.

UPDATE: Also, it seems that this is fixed on **Xcode 11.2 beta2**

Answer (score 74):

This appears to occur because SPM dependencies might not automatically be linked to test targets.

We can manually link it by:

1. Clicking on your Xcode project file (e.g. `Headlines`)
2. Select test target from the sidebar (e.g. `HeadlinesTests`)
3. Navigating to `Build Phases` in the top bar.
4. In the `Link Binary With Libraries` phase, add the required library from the SPM dependency (this looks like a white building within the SPM package ).
5. You may also need to add the library to the `Dependencies` phase.

Comment: THANK YOU! I think this is a step forward. However, in one of my projects I got now "Class XYZ is implemented in both <<path>> and <<other_path>>. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined." and then it crashes on the test.

Comment: Thank you, I had a problem with this for a long time and I couldn't understand if it was the PMS or the dependency.

Comment: I did this as well on Xcode 12 beta, but there seems to be a memory issue ```CLASS: class 'Testing.TestOne' 0x102b2b818 small method list 0x102b26e40 is not in immutable memory```

Answer (score 11):

I was facing a similar issue in Xcode 14.1. Getting error `Missing required module 'RxCocoaRuntime'`.

My fix was:

1. Go to the project target and select the Unit test target.
2. Select build phases under the Unit Test target
3. Select "Link Binary With Libraries"
4. Added RxSwift and RxCocoa packages.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this in Xcode 13 after I created a multi-platform app & had checked the box to create tests. The issue seems to be that Xcode created UI tests rather than unit tests as I had expected. I just made a new **unit test** target and everything worked as expected when importing my app in the test file.

Answer (score 0):

Before you try the above, quit Xcode, and delete your derived data folder (~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData). If you're using cocoapods, run `pod install`, and then re-open Xcode. This fixed the problem for me.