# When importing app with @testable, get “Missing required module 'CTrueTime'” using SPM

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an old project Objective-C iOS app I've been updating to Swift. It used to use Carthage, but now uses only SPM for dependencies. One such dependency is [TrueTime](https://github.com/pragnesh-is/TrueTime.swift) (which was updated to support SPM by that author).

It has two products, `TrueTime`, a Swift library, and `CTrueTime` a header-only C library with some packed, byte-aligned structs used when parsing NTP responses.

I’m adding unit tests to my project, and when I import the app module with `@testable import MyApp`, the build fails on that line with

```
@testable import MyApp
                 ^
<unknown>:0: error: missing required module 'CTrueTime'
```

The app itself builds and runs just fine.

If I don’t import the app, then I have to expressly add code I want to test to the test target, which is not the right way to do these things. The other dependencies I have all work fine, but none have a C library product.

I get a warning about implicitly including a bridging header, but I don’t think that has anything to do with this.

Is there something more I need to add to my test target config?

**Update:** I also just tried adding TrueTime to a modern, pure SwiftUI iOS app, and I get the same issue.

**Update2:** This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58630277/251914) helped me a bit. It seems the build stage is not putting the required `CTrueTime.modulemap` and associated header file in the build products location like it does for the other modules. If I manually copy it into place, *and* I add the `OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS` value `-Xcc -fmodule-map-file=$(PROJECT_TEMP_ROOT)/GeneratedModuleMaps-iphonesimulator/CTrueTime.modulemap` to the test target, it works.